# Using javascript to hide and show elements

Tags: javascript

I have gotten my form to disappear with javascript, but now I want a line of text to appear when the form is displayed as none and I'm not sure what the correct boolean operators for javascript are.

```js
<script>
    function Enter() {
        survey.style.display = "none";
        if (survey==="none"){
            thank.style.display = "inline";
        }
        else {
            thank.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

```html
<div id="right">
    <div id="thank" style=" display: none">
        Thank you, your message has been sent.
    </div>
    <form name="survey" id="survey" action="" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Contact Us!" onclick="Enter()"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Error Message:

> "message": "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'", "filename":
>   "https://stacksnippets.net/js", "lineno": 13, "colno": 28

Comment: possibly you should try if (survey.style.display == 'none') {
 thank.style.display = 'inline';
}

Comment: Try using double equal? `==` instead of `===`?

Comment: @PraveenKumar the problem with that is my JDK says it expects `===`

Comment: @briggleshiggle Why not try it once and see? Is it stopping you from running or something?

Comment: Could you add to some 'debug checkpoints' " console.log("Checkpoint x"); " to get some debug info?

Comment: @PraveenKumar No, it just doesn't make any difference to the code. It should make the text appear after the form is not displayed but it doesn't appear. Could it be something with having my element preset to the display of `none`? Should I be setting the elements original display in the script?

Comment: @briggleshiggle Can you share the HTML as well? Any errors in the console?

Comment: @PraveenKumar just edited the snippets. There is an error but I'm still struggling to figure out what it's from so I've added it in.

Comment: @PraveenKumar could it be that the if else statement shold be in a different function?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand u correctly,

You want to have a line of tekst wich is default: "display: none"
So:

```
<p id="MyTekst" style="display: none">My line of tekst</p>
```

Combine that with your script:

```
<script>
function Enter() {
    survey.style.display = "none";

    if (survey==="none"){
        thank.style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("MyTekst").style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
       thank.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

Let us know if it helped

Comment: Still failing to display the line of text once the form disapears.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with this :

```
                   <script>

                    function Enter() {
                        survey.style.display = "none";

                        if (survey.style.display==="none"){
                            thank.style.display = "inline";
                        }
                    }
                </script>
```